# Internet Speed Test App from AS3

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript-3, network-programming, speed-test

I need to create a internet speed test application in Actionscript 3.0,  like 
[Speed Test](http://www.speedtest.net/)

I need to calculate

**1. Download speed
 2. Upload speed
 3. Latency (Round Trip Time)
 4. Jitter
 5. Packet loss
 6. Network availability**

From where I should start?
Is any guides or tutorials out there regarding as3 network programming?
Please Help Me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with a simple method found here: http://yeungus.com/2009/09/07/as3-bandwidth-test/

Flash Media Server also has some bandwidth detection as the link suggests as well, but might not be exactly what you are looking for.

For doing what you are describing, I would look at the docs for [flash.net.Socket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) and see the options there. Also [flash.net.URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) could be of use, as well as looking over [flash.net](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package-detail.html) and seeing if anything else sticks out.

Comment: So is it possible to do this job using flash ActionScript 3?

Comment: I assume speedtest.net does some additional server side stuff. Since they are using Flash/ActionScirpt for their client stuff, I don't see why you couldn't do the client side stuff with Actionscript.

Comment: Yes, I will try to give my best shot. Thanks again.